# Compare variable date with Date(dateString) in if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Sorry for the n00b question, but my js/jq is terrible. I spent the better part of my afternoon on this, but I still can't figure out the last little bit.

I need to input a date, calculate the date 180 days from the inputted date, and compare that with a dateString (labelled as 'deadline' in the code below). Everything works okay, except for the if/else statement at the end. I feel like it is a simple fix, but I just can't see it. Presently, it just outputs the result of the else statement.

HTML

```
<h2>click Go! to add 180 days:</h2>
<p>Add 180 to:
<input id="indexDate" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Go!" />

<p>Result Date:
<span id="date_180"></span>
<span id="answer"></span></p>
```

JS/JQ

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#indexDate').datepicker({changeYear: true}).datepicker('setDate', '01/01/2004');
});

function getdate() {

  var tt = document.getElementById('indexDate').value;
  var date = new Date(tt);
  var newdate = new Date(date);
  var deadline = new Date(11/03/2014);

  newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 180);

  var dd = newdate.getDate();
  var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = newdate.getFullYear();

  var formattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
  document.getElementById('date_180').innerHTML = formattedDate;

  if (formattedDate<deadline) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Yay!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Boo!";
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your if condition

```
 if(new Date(formattedDate) < deadline){
     document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Yay!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Boo!";
  }
```

If not working try to format date likes

`var formattedDate = new Date(Year,Month,Day);//Date object`  [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Using both of your suggestions got things working! I did have the format of the date object wrong and I think that was causing a big part of the problem, as the two variables being compared weren't in the same format. Thank you very much for the help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think ist a Problem with the formats of the Dates.

Add

```
console.log(deadline);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

before the if Block and have a look in the console. What does it say?

Comment: You were correct. The problem was with the format of the dates. I fixed my 'deadline' date to be compliant with the javascript date object format of Year,Month,Day. Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it!